# Should I check the phone status if My app should send a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have made an app that contains a reminder so this reminder shows a notification, and the user can change the sound of the notification, so he can be reminded with a sound;
What I need to know is should I check for the phone ringing state so that if it was ringing I modify the notification sound to silent or that's done by default? thanks.
please can I have any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that yes, because when I didn't check the status and depending on the status make my app vibrate, it vibrated even when I received a phone call...
so yes I needed to check the status and make the app vibrate when the phone mode is not silent and the phone state is idle;